# How to make the expression 6÷8=27 correct

Tags: puzzle, decimal-expansion

If you have the expression 6÷8=27 how can you insert the same number into the equation twice in order to make the equation correct (no addition, multiplication, division or subtraction, just the idea that having 6 and 2 would make 62)

I've tried putting some numbers after the 6 that are below 6 so that when I put the same number before the 8 the answer will be greater that 1. i.e. 628÷288 but obviously that doesn't work. I cannot seem to come up with a method to do this sort of problem generally either

Comment: What did you try? Did you stick any 0's or 1's or 2's or anything else in there to see what might happen?

Comment: I've tried putting some numbers after the 6 that are below 6 so that when I put the same number before the 8 the answer will be greater that 1. i.e. 628÷288 but obviously that doesn't work. I cannot seem to come up with a method to do this sort of problem generally either

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but $(216)\div8=27$

Comment: it is not clear where you are allowed to put this numbers...

Comment: I came to this answer originally but you have to insert the 21 somewhere else in the equation as well as the question asks to insert the same number into the equation twice.

Comment: You could put the numbers before or after any number that is already in the equation i.e. you could put a two before or after the 6 making it 62 or 26 but because the question states you have to insert the same number twice you have to put a 2 in somewhere else as well for example, before or after the 8

Comment: Are we allowed to insert, for example $08$ behind the $6$ and $8$ behind the $8$ ? So, we would get $608:88$ ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be within the rules of the question

Comment: Easy :) : $$6^\color{red}{4}÷\color{red}{4}8=27.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we insert the same number $X$ after $6$ and before $8$ we have the equation $6X\div X8=27$, that is:
$$
6\cdot10^k+X=27(10X+8),
\quad\hbox{or}\quad
269X=6\cdot10^k-216,
$$
where $k$ is the number of digits of $X$. This has the smallest integer solution for $k=128$:
$$
\begin{align}
X=&02230483271375464684014869888475836431226765799256505576208178438\\
  &661710037174721189591078066914498141263940520446096654275092936,
\end{align}
$$
where I inserted a leading $0$ to have a total of $128$ digits.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I was looking for a solution more like this that uses algebra rather than just aimless trial and error.

Comment: @MatthewC My guess is that we can insert in another way with smaller numbers, but the solution is impressive!